# Passing class as parametr with generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

[Here is live example](http://goo.gl/bSOKQo)(Sorry, had to use url shortener, link characters break markup)
TypeScript version 1.6.2

I have two services across my angular2 application. Let's name them ServiceA and ServiceB. Each one of them, have similar data structure, so I decided to use `extends` to not write same code twice. The class which will provide data structure is called Pages and looks like this:

```
class Pages {
  public pages = [];
  private active: number = 0;

  get current() {
    return this.pages[this.active];
  }

  constructor(private page, public name: string) { }

  changeActive(page: number): void {
    this.active = page;
  }

  addPage(): void {
    this.pages.push(
      new this.page(this.name + (this.pages.length + 1))
    );
  }
}
```

`pages` array will contains class instances unique for each service. Here is an example of one for ServiceA:

```
// ServiceA.pages will be filled with instanced of this class.
// ServiceB.pages will use different class but the constructor 
// will be simmilar(will take only one argument name: string)
class PageA {
  public uniquePropertyA: string = 'Hello World!';
  constructor(public name: string) { }
  // unique methods of PageA
}
```

Services will look quite similar. Here preview of ServiceA:

```
class ServiceA extends Pages {
  constructor() {
    super(PageA, 'ServiceA #');
  }
}

// demo
var sA = new ServiceA();
sA.addPage();
sA.current. // Hey there is no auto complete!
```

This example works fine, however I do not get autocomplete each page because its type is `any`. I was trying to use "generics" to make it work, sadly with no success but [here it is](http://goo.gl/kU5H2Y). Basicly I want to know which constructor I passed to `Pages` class, so I can get right types.

I hope you guys can help me with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access page properties in the generic class because, well you are using the generic type T, so the compiler has at that point no information about how you are going to use the class later.

If you need to do actions which are bound to a specific type you can not do this in the generic class.

What you can do is, to use a generic constraint on your class. e.g.  where the BasePage is an Interface e.g.

```
interface BasePage {
   name: string;
}
```

The class would be like this:

```
class Pages<T extends BasePage>
```

You can implement your Interfaces in the PageA and PageB like this:

```
PageA implements BasePage
```

Then you would be able to have access to the name attribute in the generic class.

Updated example: http://goo.gl/Pg85Wx